# how do you specifically add elements to a 2 dimentional array?

Tags: python

With a 2 dimentional array, I only want specific elements to be a different number.
If the array was not fixed and changed dimentions, how could you loop over it with a for loop to impliment the pattern?

```
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1

0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

This is what i want to create but i cant find a way to only select those ones in a for loop.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
rows, cols = (5,5)
arr = [[0 for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]
for row in arr:
    if row == 0 or row == 1:
        print("h")
        arr[rows-1, row] = 1
    if row == 2 or row == 3:
        arr[rows-1, row] = 1
    if row == 4 or row == 5:
        arr[rows-1, row] = 1
    if row == 6 or row == 7:
        arr[rows-1, row] = 1


print(arr)
```

This is what I have so far.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to StackOverflow. How is the 2D array constructed in your case?

Comment: This is a good source about 2D arrays: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_data_structure/python_2darray.htm

Comment: Are you talking about a list of lists, or do you mean a numpy array?

Comment: Thank you for saying welcome :) I'll ammend the post to show what I have so far.

Comment: if you want to change some values you dont have to go over it with a for loop you can just access the item you need. lets say if each row is a list then two access the 2column on the second row you wold do some_array[1][1]=some_new_int and puff its changed.

Comment: yes but if the size of the array changes and i want to keep the same pattern, one would have to make a for loop for generalisation right?

Comment: yea.. your initial question was then a bit misleading. "So with a 5x5 2 dimentional array, I only want specific elements to be a different number." sounded like you have a fixed 2d array which you need to edit.

Comment: apologies, I'll ammend the question.

Comment: If you are always using a square array, then you can replace `rows, cols = (5,5)` with `rows = cols = 5`, for better readability.

Comment: Kedge - Is the array always square? Is the number of rows always odd?

Comment: Mano, yes to both of the questions

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution:

```
from pprint import pprint
n = 5
mat = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if i + j >= n - 1 and j % 2 == 0:
            mat[i][j] = 1

pprint(mat)
```

Some minor notes (this is better off in the code review forum, in truth):

1. If the matrix is always square - you need only define a single value (`n` here) and not two `rows` and `cols`. Presuming that `n` is also odd, your ones pattern is well defined.
2. `arr` is not a very good name, seeing the name 'array' usually refers to a one-dimensional array. A 'matrix' would suit better in my views [`mat` for short, of course].
3. `pprint` is a module, which allows prints out to the screen in a 'prettier' way, with respect to some python data structure, such as a list of lists. It sometimes comes in handy. Check out the differences when compared to `print`.

The key here is to recognize the pattern of ones, and implement it clearly in code. There are many patterns that may fit - but here I went with 'look only at even columns' and 'look only at the bottom right triangle of the matrix'.

Changing `n` to 11 for example, yields:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this has really helped me <3